# C# WPF application close after splash screen on some computer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop

I have a C# WPF application, which doesn't require installation. One of my clients have a weird problem:
After he use the application every day for more than 2 weeks, now when he try to open it, after showing the splash screen it close automatically.
If I update/replace the .exe from his computer still doesn't run.
If I copy the .exe on my computer it runs ok.
If I rename the .exe on his computer it runs ok.
He doesn't have any antivirus, and we both have Windows 10.

A few months ago, another client had the same problem.

Comment: Please, share more details, log files, errors, exception, source code, we can't predict it

Comment: Is customer's computer in a network? The domain network security rules can affect an app start or close the app.

Comment: Antivirus blocks it?